# ZF2 REST API + ACL doesn't return the action name in predispatch

Tags: php, api, rest, zend-framework2, acl

Ok, i have a problem, but i think it is not so complicated, so it would be great if someone helped me. 
1) I have UserController that extends AbstractRestfulController and it works fine.
2) Then i needed to check the permission to access actions of this controller. If I use "checkPermission" method in every controller it works pretty good, but I want to make this method done in a preDispatch event. And here are some problems:
I do like this:
**Module.php**

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $em = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $em->attach('dispatch', array($this, 'preDispatch'), +100);
}
```

My method "checkPermission" checks like this (nothing special I think):

```
if (!$this->isAllowed($role, $this->routeMatch->getParam('controller'), $this->routeMatch->getParam('action'))) {
```

So the problem: getParam('action') returns null (It means, that in a preDispatch event application doesn't know what action it needs to execute). How can I make it work like I want? Or here is the main question: **When does getParam('action') can return value? Only in onDispatch event?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since its a restful api, it will never return action name. in added with applying ACL to the Rest API is not a good practice.
Use Rest API Authentication HEADERS instead of ACL.
[refer this link](https://juriansluiman.nl/article/147/api-header-based-authentication-in-zend-framework-2)
--SJ